# IOS store more than one password in keychain

Tags: iphone, ios, password-protection, keychain

in my app I can save an read fine 1 password store in the keychain using this code

```
// save password
[keychainItem setObject:textFieldPassword.text forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

//get pasword from keychain
NSString *_password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
```

My question is: how can I store more than 1 password at a time in the keychain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.

Here the solution  I used:

adding to my project the files KeychainItemWrapper.h/m

allocating 2 keychain items:

```
//aloc for user password
keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"passowrdKey1" accessGroup:nil];
//aloc for user password2
keychainItem2 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"passowrdKey1" accessGroup:nil];
```

then just use this to read/write

```
//WRITE    
// save password
[keychainItem setObject:@"password1" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
// save password2
[keychainItem2 setObject:@"password2" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

//READ        
//get pasword from keychain
NSString *_pass = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

//get pasword from keychain
NSString *_pass2 = [keychainItem2 objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
```

Comment: What happens when you restart your app? When new memory is allocated for KeychainItemWrapper, how will it know which kSecValueData to show? Wont the second value just overwrite the first one?

Answer (score 2):

Keychain programming is hard. I use a wrapper class called SFHFKeychainUtils. It has very simple class methods for storing and retrieving passwords.

Check it out: https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security

You store items with keys you make up. So you could have @"WiFiPasswordKey", @"LoginPasswordKey", etc.

Comment: This is the right answer. Another relevant link to the wrapper: http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code

Comment: For what it's worth, the developer says SFHFKeychainUtils is deprecated and that [`STKeychain`](https://github.com/ldandersen/STUtils/blob/master/Security/STKeychain.h) should be used instead. But the two libraries look almost exactly the same so I'm not sure what the improvement or difference is.